# Found a recursive function summing elements in a list quite difficult to follow and I wonder if anyone could explain it to me well

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

```
def sum_recursive(L):
  if len(L) == 1:
    return L[0]

  idx = len(L) // 2
  return sum_recursive(L[:idx]) + sum_recursive(L[idx:])
```

I understand that the first condition is the base case for the function but I do not understand the `return sum_recursive(L[:idx]) + sum_recursive(L[idx:])`. Why does `sum_recursive(L[:idx])` run first and `sum_recursive(L[idx:]` after `len(L) != 1:` . Also, looks like there is a sum of a list and a single index in `sum_recursive(L[:idx]) + sum_recursive(L[idx:])` and that does not make sense to me. Thanks

Comment: Hi @kweks45. [This](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20sum_recursive%28L%29%3A%0A%20%20if%20len%28L%29%20%3D%3D%201%3A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20L%5B0%5D%0A%0A%20%20idx%20%3D%20len%28L%29%20//%202%0A%20%20return%20sum_recursive%28L%5B%3Aidx%5D%29%20%2B%20sum_recursive%28L%5Bidx%3A%5D%29%0A%0Al%20%3D%20list%28range%281,%2011%29%29%0Aprint%28l%29%0Asum_recursive%28l%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) visualization should explain better.

Comment: @Vishnudev http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20sum_recursive%28L%29%3A%0A%20%20if%20len%28L%29%20%3D%3D%201%3A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20L%5B0%5D%0A%0A%20%20idx%20%3D%20len%28L%29%20//%202%0A%20%20return%20sum_recursive%28L%5B%3Aidx%5D%29%20%2B%20sum_recursive%28L%5Bidx%3A%5D%29%0A%0Al%20%3D%20list%28range%281,%2011%29%29%0Aprint%28l%29%0Asum_recursive%28l%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=8&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false ; my worry is at this point. why did only `L[:idx]) ` get passed back to `sum_recursive()`

Comment: The return statement from sum_recursive returns the sum of sum_recusive(L[:idx] ) + sum_recursive(L[idx::]).  The function sum_recursive splits the list in half with the line idx = len(L)//2.  The slice L[:idx] is the list beginning with the first element and ending with idex-1.  The slice L[idx:] is the list from idx to the end.  this is repeated until the list is len 1, at which point it returns to the previous call and adds together the first & last list elements, the working from the ends toward the middle it adds subsequent elements to the total.  Hope this he;lps

Comment: @itprorh66 Alright, thanks. After it hits the base case, which function is executed? Or previous sum calls are executed? How does the call know to push the sum of earlier calculated list to the next list for calculation?

Comment: @itprorh66 if you could give clarification as to what each return statement does? When the base case condition is reached, it returns an index. But where does it return the index to?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I can explain with an  example:

```
sum_recursive([1,2,3,4]):
len(L) > 1, so:
idx = 4//2 = 2
return            #splits list in half and sums each half
  (   sum_recursive([1,2])
      len(L) > 1 so:
      idx = 2//2 = 1
      return      #splits list in half again and sums each half
        (   sum_recursive([1])
            len(l) = 1 so:
            return 1
        +
            sum_recursive([2])
            len(L) = 1 so
            return 2
        ) = 3 
    +
     sum_recursive([3,4])
     len(L) = 2 so:
     idx = 2//2 = 1
     return      #splits list in half abain and sums each half 
       (  sum_recursive([3])
          len(l) = 1 so:
          return 3
        +
          sum_recursive([4])
          len(L) = 1 so
          return 4
        ) = 7 
    ) = 10
```